# What is the difference between a permutation and a shuffle (transposition cipher)

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation, shuffle

A non-cryptographic definition of a permutation is "[2a: the act or process of changing the lineal order of an ordered set of objects. 2b: an ordered arrangement of a set of objects](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permutation)

The [Wikipedia article on Random permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) states that "A good example of a random permutation is the shuffling of a deck of cards: this is ideally a random permutation of the 52 cards."

An ideal block cipher is a pseudorandom permutation.

Shuffling a deck of identical cards would result in output indistinguishable from the input. Applying an ideal block cipher to an all-zero (or all-one) plaintext block would yield a random ciphertext block, not the same all-zero (or all-one) input block!

What's an easy-to-understand difference between a shuffle (equivalently a transposition cipher) and a permutation in the sense meant by cryptographers?

Comment: Looking to see if anyone has better/clearer/more intuitive answers. It's easy enough to state the difference using mathematical notation, but getting it across clearly without that seems a bit harder.

Comment: I do not understand the distinction you are trying to make. Could you try to clarify it some? This is likely complicated because a [transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions) has a well-defined mathematical meaning which appears to be distinct from what you mean (in particular, transpositions are permutations which interchange exactly two elements, so the subset of transpositions is a subset of the set of all permutations. The subgroup generated by these elements is the full permutation group though).

Comment: Swapped it to "transposition cipher" since that's the more precise term I was going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue your deck of cards analogy, the permutation is analogous to replacing each card in a set with one from a full deck.  With a new full deck for each card.

If someone can understand that, then they can understand that each card represents 4 digits/etc and that the deck of cards is 10k/etc in size.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's a good answer, and keeps the same analogy. Though there's the additional restriction that a permutation must be bijective, but that's easy enough to tack on.

Answer (score 2):

A shuffle (or transposition function) re-arranges elements of the input. A permutation re-arranges the entire output domain.

For example, compare the following transposition function and pseudorandom permutation:
The transposition takes in a 4-digit number, and re-arranges the digits. 1234 might become 4213, but never 1692.
A pseudorandom permutation has a shuffled list of all possible 4-digit numbers, and an unshuffled list of all possible 4-digit numbers. It looks up the input number in the unshuffled list, finds the corresponding number in the shuffled list, and outputs that. 1234 might become 1692.